# How to make a REST GET request (with authentication) and parse the result in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, marklogic

Due to circumstances beyond my control, `Javascript` is the only language option available for me. I'm a beginner and am not even sure if I'm approaching the problem in a "recommended" manner.

Simply put, a customer has setup a `MarkLogicDB` server online and has given me read-only access. I can query the server with the **HTTP GET protocol** to return an `XML` document that has to be parsed. I've been able to create a `curl` command to return the data I need (example below);

```
curl --anyauth --user USERNAME:PASSWORD \
  -X GET \
  http://test.com:8020/v1/documents?uri=/path/to/file.xml
```

The above returns the requested `XML` file. Can someone please show me how I could convert the above to `javascript` code? Additionally, how would I parse the data? Let's say I want to get all the info from a certain element or attribute. How can this be accomplished?

This would be trivial for me to do in `Java/.NET`, but after reading plenty of online tutorials on Javascript, my head is spinning. Every tutorial talks about web-browsers, but I'm doing this on a server environment (The [parse.com CloudCode](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#logging)). There isn't any UI or HTML involved. For debugging, I just read the logs created with `console.log()`.

Comment: You won't be able to go too far without javascript knowledge. You should learn javascript for implementing anything worthwhile.

Comment: I *am* studying Javascript - its just that every single tutorial assumes that I'm working with a web browser and I don't want to waste time learning something I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking seems pretty clear, as far as it goes.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://test.com:8020/v1/documents',
  params: {
    uri : '/path/to/file.xml'
  },
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse.text);
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
  }
});
```

But you'll also need authentication. The `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` docs don't include any examples for that. If you have support with that vendor, **ask the vendor about digest authentication**.

If you're stuck you might try adding `user` and `password` to the `httpRequest` params and see what happens. It might work, if the developers of this stack followed the XMLHttpRequest convention.

Failing support from the vendor and existing functionality, you'll have to implement authentication yourself, in JavaScript. This works by generating strings that go into the request headers. These resources should help:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Basic auth is much easier to implement, but I'd recommend using digest for security reasons. If your HTTPServer doesn't support that, try to get the configuration changed.

Comment: Hmm... when I first saw those pages, due the lack of USERNAME/PASSWORD fields, assumed that it wasn't relevant. Will send a query to vendor about this. Thanks for the pointer!