# Parse.com Cloud Code Evaluate xPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, parse-platform, cloud

I am new to using Parse.com cloud code, and am mainly a iOS developer. In iOS I use Hpple, an xPath evaluator to parse an xml document. I now need to do this in my cloud code. I was wondering if there is already a way in the Javascript SDK to do this with expressions like

xpath expression:

```
//day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='LUNCH']/counter[@name='Deli']/dish/name
```

to evaluate this xml from this url:

```
http://64.182.231.116/~spencerf/union_college/Upperclass_Sample_Menu.xml
```

This would return the strings "Made to Order Deli Core", "Caprese Panini Biggie Sandwich". Is there a way to do this in the Javascript SDK or are there any modules that I can install into parse's cloud code that can evaluate xml like this?

The code I have tried so far is this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("next", function(request, response) {

  var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'http://64.182.231.116/~spencerf/union_college/Upperclass_Sample_Menu.xml',
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        //console.log(httpResponse.text);
        var someXml = httpResponse.text;

        xmlreader.read(someXml, function (err, res){
            if(err) return console.log(err);

            // use .text() to get the content of a node:
            console.log( res.dish.text() );

        });

    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
  });


});
```

I can get the data saved in my variable someXml, I think it is saved as a string, which is maybe messing with the parsing because I am unable to parse it. I am using `xmlReader` to parse it (`https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmlreader`) there is the link with how it works and the syntax for parsing. I am having trouble parsing it though. Ideally I would like to just parse it with xPath where I was using this code:

```
    var getElementByXpath = function (path) {
  return someXml.evaluate(path, someXml, null, 2, null).stringValue;

  };
  console.log(getElementByXpath("//day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='LUNCH']/counter[@name='Deli']/dish/name"));
```

But this was not working, it gave me this error

```
has no method 'evaluate'
at getElementByXpath (main.js:131:20)
at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:134:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:571:19)
```

On the link I provided I would like to get all the name nodes under monday/lunch

Comment: That path does not select anything as there is no `name` element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm just using this path and xml as a simple example, I'm wondering how to use xPath in java, to get nodes

Comment: You seem to confuse JavaScript and the Java SDK as you mention both. So which language do you use? Also, as far as I know parse.com just handles JSON and not XML.

Comment: @dirkk I am using the Javascript SDK that is used on Parse.com cloud code. And I have the xml document saved on my server so I would retrieve it from the web, which can be done and then I just need to parse it with some sort xPath, but I am not sure how to do that? does that clarify things?

Comment: You've adjusted the code in your question with the function from my answer, and this won't work for you like that. The content of your XML file is stored in the variable someXml, so maybe you have to adjust "return document.evaluate" to "someXml.evaluate" and so on as document is not defined.

Comment: @matthias_h I changed the code and now returned the following error, that is now in the question

Comment: @spenf document.evaluate belongs to javascript, so both won't work (only in the example in the answer for parsing XML with javascript). for parsing XML in cloud code have a look at e.g. the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000277/unable-to-parse-data-from-an-xml-file-in-the-parse-cloud-using-xmlreader-in-expr  . for parsing the XML in your setting you should just use the cloud code xml-parser functions/syntax.

Comment: @matthias_h okay I see I looked that up, but how does it know what document to use

Comment: @spenf maybe a misunderstanding. I'd think you already have your XML stored as variable/object "someXml". So you just have to parse this - "document" in the js-example is similar to the "someXml" in your cloude code. The "evalute" function belongs to javascript which you don't need - just check the example of the XMLReader you installed (link above in your question). You can get the nodes by name with a function like "xmlreader.read(someXml, function (err, res){ ... console.log( res.name.text() ); }" for the XPath //day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='LUNCH']/counter[@name='Deli']/dish/name

Comment: @spenf as you updated your question - you should get your dish-names with a function like "for(var i = 0; i < res.day.meal.counter.dish.name.count(); i++){ console.log( res.day.meal.counter.dish.name.at(i).text() );"
    }

Comment: @matthias_h with this code `for(var i = 0; i < res.day.meal.counter.dish.name.count(); i++){ 
console.log( res.day.meal.counter.dish.name.at(i).text() ); }`
I get this error ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'meal' of undefined
    at main.js:150:31`

Comment: @spenf - in your XML are some days at the end without a meal, can you for testing purpose delete them and test again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is good right here

```
xmlreader.read(someXml, function (err, res){
if(err) return console.log(err);
for(var i = 0; i < res.day.count(); i++){
  if (res.day(i).text()) == "monday")
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < res.day(i).meal.count(); j++){
      if (res.day(i).meal(j).text() == "LUNCH")
      {
        for(var k = 0; k < res.day(i).meal(j).counter.dish; k++){
          console.log( res.day(i).meal(j).counter.dish(k).name.text());
        }
      } 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible in Parse.com regarding possible restrictions mentioned in above comments (user dirkk), but maybe this could work / help:

```
var getElementByXpath = function (path) {
 return document.evaluate(path, document, null, 2, null).stringValue;
};
alert(getElementByXpath("//book/title"));
```

Working Demo: [Javascript XPath](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/fszam72r/)

Update: above XML-parsing with Javascript by XPath was included in OP. Though it could work, next issue was to get XML-file by URL. Suggested solution using Ajax / jQuery wasn't preferred by OP. Suggested to use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` instead. Find reference here: [Cloud Code Response Object](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking). In addtion, similar problem with solution mentioned here: [Unable to parse data from an xml file in the Parse Cloud using xmlreader in express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000277/unable-to-parse-data-from-an-xml-file-in-the-parse-cloud-using-xmlreader-in-expr) and here: [How to make a REST GET request (with authentication) and parse the result in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426137/how-to-make-a-rest-get-request-with-authentication-and-parse-the-result-in-jav)
Maybe useful to have a look here: [Parse Cloud Code](http://de.slideshare.net/pa4373/parse-cloud-code)

Update: As question has been adjusted, Parse Cloud xmlreader is now tested to get the monday lunch names from the XML-File. As documentation of xmlreader doesn't offer to access a node attribute by attribute value directly, following solution, though it looks ugly because of nested for-loops, could work:

```
xmlreader.read(someXml, function (err, res){
if(err) return console.log(err);
for(var i = 0; i < res.day.count(); i++){
  if (res.day(i).text()) == "monday")
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < res.day(i).meal.count(); j++){
      if (res.day(i).meal(j).text() == "LUNCH")
      {
        for(var k = 0; k < res.day(i).meal(j).counter.dish; k++){
          console.log( res.day(i).meal(j).counter.dish(k).name.text());
        }
      } 
   }
 }
```

Update: As parsing using javascript xpath-like functions is preferred and Parse doesn't seem to offer yet XML Parsing with Xpath - https://parse.com/questions/htmlxml-parser-with-xpath-on-cloud-code statement at the bottom - and recommends to include appropriate javascript-library or node.js instead - find example here: https://temboo.com/nodejs/parsing-xml - maybe this would help. If not already tried, check https://parse.com/questions/can-we-importrequireinclude-any-other-javascript-files-in-our-cloud-code

Comment: if the xml is at a url, how would I get the if from a url?

Comment: @spenf you can get if from a url using ajax - instead of going into detail here have a look at e.g. : [http://webtutsdepot.com/2009/12/16/how-to-read-xml-with-javascript/](http://webtutsdepot.com/2009/12/16/how-to-read-xml-with-javascript/).

Comment: I got this error "$ is not defined
    at main.js:124:3", I have added my code to the question

Comment: @spenf you already include jquery.js? and would be helpful to know the line 124 of your main.js.

Comment: this line is where I get the error: `$.ajax({` and I don't know what you mean by "you already include jquery.js?"

Comment: @spenf just to be sure - I guess you know about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? in case you're using $.ajax, you have to download the jquery-library and include it in your page

Comment: No I don't. Are you saying I need to download it and add it to the web page? or the browser?

Comment: @spenf yes, just download the latest version and include it in your web page. in case you're new to jQuery have a look at the jQuery link above (jQuery is a useful javascript-framework) and in case of ajax-problems consider posting an ajax-related question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59690/discussion-between-spenf-and-matthias-h).

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out and get you started

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("next", function(request, response) {

  var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'http://64.182.231.116/~spencerf/union_college/Upperclass_Sample_Menu.xml',
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        //console.log(httpResponse.text);
        var someXml = httpResponse.text;
    xmlreader.read(someXml, function (err, res){
        if(err) return console.log(err);

        // use .text() to get the content of a node:
        console.log( res.dish.text() );

    });

},
error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
}
```